# working with the FGallery image viewer

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to implement the FGallery imageviewer. I have a method which gives me an array of all URL's of photo's that I want to show. Next I have the the following methods of FGallery implemented.

```
- (int)numberOfPhotosForPhotoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery
{
     return [_picturesForAlbum count];

}

- (FGalleryPhotoSourceType)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery sourceTypeForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
     return FGalleryPhotoSourceTypeNetwork;
}


- (NSString*)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery urlForPhotoSize:(FGalleryPhotoSize)size atIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [_picturesForAlbum objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

And in my didSelectRowForIndexPath I did this.

```
networkGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self.picturesForAlbum];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:networkGallery animated:YES];
```

But I don't know what I should put in the initWithPhotoSource. When I have it like this. I keep getting the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM numberOfPhotosForPhotoGallery:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc95bb60'
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

delegate i.e. self. It will call the delegate methods.
[[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];